# Excel 2010 List unique values in column A if there are specific values in column B

Tags: excel, list

I've seen a lot of similar questions (mostly involving counting instead of listing), but I can't find exactly what I'm looking for anywhere.

What I want to do is return a list of all unique values in column A, IF they have certain corresponding values in column B, example:

[image]

How would I generate a list of all the foods that are either $1 or $2? I want to be able to regularly update my data and have the list update automatically.

Thank you!

Comment: What have you done so far? Can you share the code that isn't working?

Comment: How big is the list and what do you expect the output to look like?  Do you  expect it to all be in one cell ore in their own cells?

Comment: I'm expecting the output to be ~800 values and I want them to each be in their own cell.

Comment: I saw this array formula in a similar question and tried to edit it to suit my needs but couldn't figure out how to: =INDEX($A$2:$A$20, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($B$1:B1, $A$2:$A$20), 0))

Answer (score 0):

This is a way of getting the answer in column C based on the formula you quoted but with a condition that the value in B=2:-

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$20, MATCH(1, (COUNTIF($C$1:$C1, $A$2:$A$20)=0)*($B$2:$B$20=2), 0)),"")
```

If you wanted to list the ones with prices 1 OR 2, it's a bit more awkward:-

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$20, MATCH(1, (COUNTIF($C$1:$C1, $A$2:$A$20)=0)*SIGN(($B$2:$B$20=1)+($B$2:$B$20=2)), 0)),"")
```

Or it might be a bit easier with this approach:-

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$20,SMALL(IF(($B$2:$B$20=1)+($B$2:$B$20=2),ROW($B$2:$B$20)-ROW($B$1)),ROWS($C$1:$C1))),"")
```